# Lightningchartjs - keep tooltip open when user clicks on chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, tooltip, lightningchart

I am using LighthingChartJS and reactJS.

I am trying to keep the current tooltip open when the user clicks on the graph.

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the resultbox you can add a marker on mouse click this can be done by:-

```js
//attaching an on click event to the seires
series.onMouseClick( ( series, event ) => {
    
    //adding a marker to the series
    const marker = series.addMarker()
    marker.setTickMarkerXVisibility( UIVisibilityModes.always )
    marker.setTickMarkerYVisibility( UIVisibilityModes.always )

    //set the marker position to the current mouse position
    marker.setPosition( 
        series.solveNearestFromScreen( 
            chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine( event.clientX, event.clientY ) 
        ).location 
    )
} )
```

In order to make the marker disappear you could add another event to dispose off the marker say for example you could add an event on mousedouble click:-

```js
series.onMouseDoubleClick( () => {
    marker.dispose()
})
```